# Remove urls from Switch to branch/Tag History

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, branch, subclipse

My Project -> Team -> Switch to another Brance/Tag/revision

I want to remove some urls from the history:

[image]

How should I do that?

I want to learn about how to create branches and how to switch from branch to trunk and ...
I could not find any good tutorial or youtube tutorial yet. If you know some please let me know.

Comment: I recommend you to use TortoiseSVN, you can manage those things easily in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no UI in Eclipse to edit these remembered values. They are just stashed away in the preference store.  It only remembers a handful of URL's so they will go away as you add more.  They should not be causing any problems.  It just remembers then for convenience.

Comment: I want to learn more about subclipse specially create branches, switch to branches, merge and etc in eclipse. Do you know any tutorial that can help me in this way?

Comment: I always recommend the SVN book - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html  You should be able to find stuff via Google.  You ought to just focus on SVN itself, as Subclipse is just a client to those features.